# PHPExcel write-on-the-fly?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Looking for a PHP class to generate HUGE xlsx files, without having to allocate huge memory for the entire file to fit in memory.

We love PHPExcel but need a way to write-on-the-fly, versus loading the entire file in memory, then calling a function to write it.

Seen a similar question, but no clear pointer to a solution.

To clarify -

You have 1GB of available memory and need to generate a 3GB Excel file.

Is there an existing class/method to accomplish this?

Comment: If you don't need formulas/formatting, you can do it as a CSV file and pretend it's an .xlsx. CSV is super-easy to stream out in pieces.

Comment: how complicated is your data? if it's simple and linear, perhaps you could write as csv and import to excel later

Comment: Thanks - Yes I know we can use CSV / TXT etc.  But we specifically have a requirement for Excel.  The file is downloaded by clients from our web service and has to look nice (simple headers, company logo etc)

Comment: Which of the PHPExcel cell caching options have you tried using to reduce the memory requirements?

Comment: Mark - we tried all of them.  Caching does help a bit, but we truly need to support spreadsheets of virtually UNLIMITED size.  Even with caching turned on, there's just no way we could generate a 3gb spreadsheet with 1gb of available memory.  So we are specifically looking for a way to generate .xlsx spreadsheets using a write-on-the-fly buffer.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yay!

We ended up solving this by writing our own PHP Excel class, capable of generating xlsx files of UNLIMITED size, by writing on-the-fly (never loading all data into memory).

Thank you to everyone who contributed your feedback and ideas! **Much appreciated**.

Our class doesn't have all the bells & whistles phpexcel.codeplex offers.  We do support fonts, basic styling and automatic sheet creation when your dataset exceeds 1 million rows.

Going to clean-up the class and put it on **Github** for everyone to use.  I'll update this post with the url as soon as it's available.

Comment: And, have you put it on Github already? :-) We're facing the same issues, so I ended up finding this answer. It would be very nice if there is already a good library.

Comment: Please post your solution somewhere, anywhere, or contribute it to the PHPExcel project.

Answer (score 0):

The secret to creating xlsx file is to write them as HTML tables, it's a super quick way to create basic Excel spreadsheets.

The trick is to write an HTML table and save it with a .xlsx extension. Then it can be opened by Excel. Simple.

And with HTML you can create those nice headers with company logos. It has everything!

Comment: Sweet trick! Going to test it out and verify Excel and OpenOffice open these html-renamed-xlsx files without complaining.

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I discovered it on accident, and found that it really cuts down on file size! :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Are you sure it works properly with xlsx files? Isn't an xlsx file a ZIP of xml files by definition?

Comment: It does work, but you have to save it with a .xls extension. Not .xlsx

Comment: Don't save html with a .xls extension unless you want your users complaining that Excel issues a warning message whenever they try to open the file... the latest versions of Excel do that, and (even though they will then read the file) it gives a bad user experience. As a professional developer, I don't like giving users an "amateurish" UX like that.

Comment: Thanks Mark, great to have you join the discussion!  .xls won't work for us because we need more than 65k lines.

Comment: Mark - any way to do this write-on-the-fly with PHPExcel?

Comment: I up voted your question. I'm interested in finding a way to write xlsx files with php...

Comment: @Mike - Excel files aren't particularly conducive to "write as you go"... it's complicated enough writing all the files that make up an xlsx anyway, and for any given cell, that might entail writing to more than a dozen different xml files. If speed isn't an issue, use cell caching... the latest SVN code supports caching to SQLite, which uses the database itself for the cell mapping so it's the lowest memory usage possible with PHPExcel.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Question: With the latest SVN code, caching to SQLite, do you expect PHPExcel to support generating a 3GB Excel spreadsheet, comprising of 10 simple text columns, no formatting, no formulas, using max 1GB of memory?

Comment: @Mike - If using SQLite caching, and setting the writer to use disk caching using the setUseDiskCaching() method, then I see no reason why not... it's certainly worth testing creating a file that large, though performance is likely to be slow. You can get a feel for the memory usage with a smaller file from the initial performance stats I posted for each caching method in http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/234150?ProjectName=phpexcel

Comment: For anyone interested - it didn't work.  We're getting about 20MB peak memory usage with only 5k rows!  It's sad.  We need to be able to generate spreadsheets of 1m rows and larger.  At current conditions, this will consume 4GB of memory.  The search continues!  Would appreciate any ideas